# Throwing an std::out_of_range exception C++

Tags: c++, exception

I have the following code below:

```
template <typename X>
const X& ArrayList<X>::at(unsigned int index) const
{
    try {
       return data[index]; //return the value of the index from the array    
    }
    catch (std::out_of_range outofrange) { //if the index is out of range
       std::cout << "OUT OF RANGE" << outofrange.what(); //throw this exception
    }
}
```

So if i have an array with values

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.at(5);
```

should throw an exception "OUT OF RANGE" but it spits out the value 0. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: You should catch exceptions by const reference.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that `data[index]` doesn't throw exception if the index goes out of range because it is not supported by the type of `data`. What is the type of `data`? Is it an array like `X data[N]`?

If so, then do the check yourself:

```
template <typename X>
const X& ArrayList<X>::at(unsigned int index) const
{
    if ( index >= _size )
        throw std::out_of_range("ArrayList<X>::at() : index is out of range");
    return data[index]; 
}
```

Note that `_size` is assumed to be size of the so-called container `data`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried this way before too but it said:
   
    terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: OUT OF RANGE
    make: *** [run] Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: The type depends on the user, thats why it has a template class.

Comment: @user3920913: You should `catch` the exception when you call this function. The problem is not with this code. The problem is, you don't catch the exception thrown by this function. So I would suggest you to read about `try-catch` before writing any code further.

Comment: I thought i did catch the exception on my code? `catch (std::out_of_range)`

Comment: @user3920913: That's wrong. What *value* do you return from the function if you catch the exception in the `at()` function itself?

Comment: Well, if it goes to the exception it should just throw the exception. But if it passes that , it should just return the value of the index `data[index]`

Comment: @user3920913 But you are catching the exception. So you need to return something.

Comment: i just want the program to end if it catches the exception, so i don't know what i would return.

Comment: @user3920913: Read about exceptions. Read A LOT about exceptions.